# Error: Razorpay Intregration with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay in flutter, but it will give error while I open my checkout page and also while I try to make payment it will give error. Both errors are in logs only but there is no effect in UI.

While I open my logs:

```
E/com.razorpay.checkout(30246): 
Webview JS Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
I/chromium(30246): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token", 
source: https://api.razorpay.com/v1/checkout/public?version=1.6.10&library=checkoutjs&platform=android (1)
```

While I try to make payment.

```
Webview JS Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: otpPermissionCallback is not defined
I/chromium(30246): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: otpPermissionCallback is not defined", 
source: https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_IGKSaWyze2xhnN/callback/162550f452294ea474c516f
251bc4ddaa6df0fd2/rzp_test_il0OViv0cegj1c?status=authorized&token_recurring_status=rejected&language_code=en 
(1)
E/ActivityThread(30246): Activity com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.razorpay.AutoRe
adOtpHelper@7396e7c that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I am trying with : razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.6
I have also tried with: razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.7
But the problem remains same.

Comment: did u find a solution for this, I'm also facing the same issue.